# Calculate price drop same or next day

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with `RIC`(string), `open`(money) and `Date`(mm/dd/yyyy) format. I need to see when the price drop was `>=25%` and whether it happened on same day or next day.

[image]

For example, `ASF` had price drop of `>=25%` in same day and `XLF` on next day so output needs to be [image]

Can you please help.

Comment: If you are using `SQL Server 2012` or above check out `Lead` and `Lag` function. Example: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Do you have a time or incremental value? Without it, you won't be able to detect same-day drops because a table is an unordered set of rows.

Comment: In you example price2 column has a wrong value.  It will be 16.5. I cannot edit as you have it as a picture.

Comment: @DanGuzman yeah, DateTime is timestamp. There is another column Epoch which is incremental timestamp for a RIC.

Comment: @vkb, I suggest you add the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statement to make your question clearer. The text says the column data type is date and in mm/dd/yyyy format (not sure what that means since datetime values are binary). .

Comment: What query(s) have you tried so far?  You're more likely to get a response to help tweak/fix **your** query as opposed to writing a query from scratch; I'd recommend taking a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then come back here and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your current DATE format leaves you without knowing which row is where.

Unless you have a database key such as a primary `ID` or durable key (easy for counting how many changes per day) that increments consistently, there is no way you are going to know which row goes where.

The best you can do with your current data is show `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG` values, and anything else with statistics to show trends per **day**...which is not that bad.

My suggestion is to immediately implement a new data type [DATETIMEOFFSET |Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql),  where you could also keep track of changes in different time zones.  Then your solution will fit geographically as well

For more information, see [date and time data types | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types)